# Do native speaker teachers who have learnt a second language teach better?

Tags: teaching, native-language

Suppose there are two groups of teachers of a language, all native speakers. One group has the experience of learning a second language and the another group doesn't. Is there research that studied which group of teachers teach better?

Comment: You teach better when you understand what it takes to learn a language, which you can learn from having learned a second language yourself. Seems obvious, doesn't it?

Comment: @Lambie Maybe. I wouldn't assume that, however. In any case, you need a skill to teach. I've met loads of native speakers (who also learned other languages) who I'm quite sure would make terrible language teachers of their native language, whereas I've met many great teachers who followed the practice of speaking only one language in the language classroom. It's possible that those teachers also learned other languages (e.g. in school) or part of their language teaching training. But usually those details never came up in the classroom, in my experience.

Comment: @Brandin You did not properly read what I said. I said that when a language teacher has learned another language, it seems obvious that s/he **would understand** what **learning another language is like**, and this would inform their teaching. Again, this seem obvious to me. The question was not about teachers or great teachers or skilled teachers. It was about whether a language teacher who has had to learn another language will **understand** what that means and that will help their teaching.